# NServiceBus. Handling specified messages in a queue

Tags: nservicebus

We use a windows service based on NServiceBus.Host to handling certain type of messages (say Message A) which are sent from some web services (messages are used as commands). In the future we want to update our services and introduce new type of messages (say Message B).

Is it possible in case of single queue to configure endpoints in old and new version of the windows service that each will handle only messages it knows about (old version - only Message A, new version - only Message B) and leave in the queue all the rest?

If it's impossible then a obvious solution is to have own queue for each type of message and I suppose own endpoint for each queue. Okay, let's assume we want to support in the future not only new messages (Message B) but also old (Message A). Are there ways to implement this (multiple endpoints) in scope of single host process or single way is using two host processes (accordingly two windows services) for each endpoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about NServiceBus it's support for inheritance. If you have a look at the documentation I think you will find what you are after.

http://particular.net/articles/messages-as-interfaces

There is also a detailed example on http://particular.net/articles/versioning-sample